# Not able to handle open URL with custom protocol if application created with electron is not installed on machine u

Tags: url, browser, electron, deep-linking, electron-builder

I have button on webpage and I have an electron based desktop application. I am able to open this application which I made using electron if it is installed in machine but problem occurs when application is not installed in machine. If I am opening not installed application from custom scheme(deep-link URL), it is throwing error on my side like "Module is not found" '

has any one faced such kind of issue?

For better clarification
I am attaching the screenshots of the error dialogs I'm getting, I have tried to put open URL code in try catch but dialog is still getting opened,

****conclusion** : I want to check that if any app is not registered with that protocol on machine (it means app is not installed in machine), I want to show a dialog that app is not installed or disable the button from
which I am going to open that application**

here are the screenshots.
[image]

here is the electron json file.

```
  "protocols": {
    "name": "electron-deep-linking",
    "schemes": [
      "xyz"
    ]
  },
```

while i have regisered the protocol in js file

```
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('xyz');
```

now I'm calling the custom protocol URL from Web page's button which is opened in browser using below code

```
window.location.assign("xyz://");
```

so while my app is installed above code manages to open my installed app, while when my app is not installed I throw dialogs as attached screen shots.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell what's wrong. Please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to include it, in accordance with [ask]. Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I have attached the sample code which can help you understanding the problem. it was not able to put fiddle here else I would have.
please upvote if you like able to understand the problem